# In React/Gatsby how can I animate a sticky header using CSS keyframes when I don't have access to the document object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, gatsby, netlify

I have a sticky header made in React/Gatsby, it shows only after you scroll down for a bit. It works but the header pops up really abruptly so I tried to animate it. The problem is I'm trying to use CSS keyframes using the `insertRule` document property and hosting platforms like Netlify don't have access to the `document` object so whenever it builds, I get this error:

```
error "document" is not available during server side rendering.
```

I researched and I can't find any suitable solutions, jsdom doesn't seem like it would solve it and I tried using styled components, doesn't work.

Here's the keyframe CSS and style insertion using `insertRule`:

```
let styleSheet = document.styleSheets[0];

const keyframesFixed = `
    @keyframes headerAnimationFixed{
        0%{
            opacity: 0.7;
            transform: translateY(-100%);
        }
        100%{
            opacity: 1;
            transform: translateY(0);
        }
    }
`;

styleSheet.insertRule(keyframesFixed, styleSheet.cssRules.length);
```

And here is how I'm using the animation:

```
const fixedStyles = {
    position: 'fixed',
    zIndex: '200',
    top: '0',
    left: '0',
    animation: 'headerAnimationFixed 0.3s ease',
    transition: 'all ease 0.3s'
}
```

Using state, I determine wether the user has scrolled down far enough, if so, the `fixedStyles` are applied.

Is there another way I can use `keyframes` in a Header component without using the `document` object?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: [The Gatsby documentation covers how to conditionally check for the presence of browser-only globals like `document` here](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/#how-to-check-if-window-is-defined).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see (and as you pointed) in the [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/), `document` and other global objects (such as `window`) are not available in the SSR. There are multiple solutions to bypass this issue, but in your case, the most simple is just to check if `window` is available to trigger the animations. If so, this will mean that you are not in the SSR. Something like this should work:

```
if (typeof window != "undefined"){
let styleSheet = document.styleSheets[0];

const keyframesFixed = `
    @keyframes headerAnimationFixed{
        0%{
            opacity: 0.7;
            transform: translateY(-100%);
        }
        100%{
            opacity: 1;
            transform: translateY(0);
        }
    }
`;

styleSheet.insertRule(keyframesFixed, styleSheet.cssRules.length);
}
```

Alternatively, if your wrapper doesn't allow `if` statements (JSX), you can add a ternary condition:

```
let styleSheet = typeof window != "undefined" ? document.styleSheets[0] : null;

const keyframesFixed = `
    @keyframes headerAnimationFixed{
        0%{
            opacity: 0.7;
            transform: translateY(-100%);
        }
        100%{
            opacity: 1;
            transform: translateY(0);
        }
    }
`;

typeof window != "undefined" ? styleSheet.insertRule(keyframesFixed, styleSheet.cssRules.length) : null;
```